# Is there a way to let the printer handling multiple copies when printing using gdi plus?

Tags: winapi, gdi+

I'm printing using the hDC I get from the print dialog and was wondering if there's a way to let the printer/printer driver/OS handle multiple copies and collation settings? I can of course print the pages multiple times, but that doesn't feel like the right way to go about this...

This is roughly what my code looks like now:

```
ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken = 0;
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup( &gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL );

DOCINFO documentInfo;
memset( &documentInfo, 0, sizeof( documentInfo ) );
documentInfo.cbSize = sizeof( documentInfo );
theDocumentInfo.lpszDocName = mDocumentName;

HDC printerHDC = printDialogData.hDC; // printDialogData is PRINTDLG struct from PrintDlg

::StartDoc( printerHDC, &documentInfo );

for( int page = 0; page < numberOfPages; ++ page )
{
    ::StartPage( printerHDC );
    // print the page
    ::EndPage( printerHDC );
}

::EndDoc( printerHDC );
::DeleteDC( printerHDC );
Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown( gdiplusToken );
```

Comment: As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-printdlgexw): *"When `PrintDlgEx` returns, `nCopies` contains the actual number of copies the application must print. This value depends on whether the application or the printer driver is responsible for printing multiple copies. If the `PD_USEDEVMODECOPIESANDCOLLATE` flag is set in the Flags member, `nCopies` is always 1 on return, and the printer driver is responsible for printing multiple copies."*

Comment: I somehow missed that part of the documentation :-(
Thanks. BTW: I can't find the option to mark my question as answered. I'm suspecting this is because there are only comments an no "answer" posts...

Comment: @gvanvoor "*I'm suspecting this is because there are only comments an no "answer" posts*" - yes, exactly.  IInspectable should have posted his info as a proper answer, not as a comment